# Печать в WPF C#, Ориентация листа

Tags: c#, wpf, print

Есть метод который создаёт окно предварительного просмотра:

```
public void Print_WPF(FrameworkElement wpf_el)
{
    if (File.Exists("print_preview.xps"))
        File.Delete("print_preview.xps");

    XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument("print_preview.xps", FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);

    SerializerWriterCollator output_Doc = writer.CreateVisualsCollator();
    output_Doc.BeginBatchWrite();
    output_Doc.Write(wpf_el);
    output_Doc.EndBatchWrite();

    FixedDocumentSequence preview = doc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
    doc.Close();

    var window = new Window();
    window.Content = new DocumentViewer { Document = preview };
    window.ShowDialog();

    writer = null;
    output_Doc = null;
    doc = null;
}
```

В окне создаётся лист но оно в книжной ориентации но мне нужно в альбомной, как это сделать?

Comment: Решил проблему!